# Calculate standard deviation for each row(rows contains list)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to calculate standard deviation of "series" for each row but the problem is every row in my column has a nested list.

My data frame  is like this:

| number | series |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 69,1,33,1,51,13,88,75,632 |
| 2 | 9,1,400,1,51,13,27,5,132 |
| 3 | 9,1,3,1,5,13,21,5,3 |
| 4 | 1,1,343,1,51,13,74,27,3 |
| 5 | 9,1,73,1,51,13,94,75,2 |

Answer (score 4):

If the series is a list

`df["std"] = df["series"].apply(np.std)`

If the series is a string

`df["std"] = df["series"].apply(lambda x: [int(i) for i in x.split(",")]).apply(np.std)`

Comment: An important note: np.std does not apply [Bessel's correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction). It won't matter on larger samples, but for small lists like in example it might make difference

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I posted just an example , because I have more than 300 number in each row , please do you have another solution